# Massing table with users

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a User mapping of of a class in my system, these Users can be friends with each other, so each User has a list of Users that they are friends with, but when I create it there is no table for friends and no column with `FriendList` in the User table created.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {

        Games = new List<Game>();
        Stats = new UserStats { Rating = 1500 };
    }

    public User(string username, string password)
    {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
        Games = new List<Game>();
        FriendList = new List<User>();
        Stats = new UserStats { Rating = 1500 };
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Username { get; set; }
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public virtual UserStats Stats { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<User> FriendList { get; set; } 
}

public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("UserId")
            .GeneratedBy
            .HiLo("100");
        Map(x => x.Username)
            .Not.Nullable();
        Map(x => x.Password)
            .Not.Nullable();
        HasMany(x => x.Games)
            .Cascade.All();
        References(x => x.Stats)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Cascade.All();
        HasMany(x => x.FriendList)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Should I instead make a friendtable with these setup instead?

```
public class FriendConnection
{
    public int Id;
    public int Friend1ID;
    public int Friend2ID;
}
```

Or can I get this other setup to work?

This is the session factory I use for it

```
public class SessionFactory
{
    private static readonly string ConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    private static ISessionFactory _session;
    private static readonly object SyncRoot = new Object();

    private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration
            .Standard
            .ConnectionString(ConnString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
                .ExposeConfiguration(UpdateSchema)
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    //
    private static void UpdateSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(false, true);
    }

    public static ISession Session
    {
        get
        {
            if (_session == null)
            {
                lock (SyncRoot)
                {
                    if (_session == null)
                        _session = CreateSessionFactory();
                }
            }
            return _session.OpenSession();
        }
    }

    private ISessionFactory CreateTables()
    { 
        return Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration
            .Standard
            .ConnectionString(ConnString))
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
                .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserMap>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static void ExportSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        var schemaexport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
        schemaexport.Drop(false, true);
        schemaexport.Create(false, true);

    }

    public ISession OpenCreateTablesSession()
    {

        _session = _session ?? (_session = CreateTables());

        return _session.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any user could be friend of any user, you will need ManyToMany mapping:

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.FriendList)
    .Table("FriendConnection")
    .ParentKeyColumn("Friend1ID")
    .ChildKeyColumn("Friend2ID");
```

No C# entity as a *man-in-the-middle* is needed.

But the issue is, that such a Friend's list has current instance as a *Parent owner*. So *I (as a user)* am owning the relation (as a *parent*). Other words, I could be also the *child* of other reference. That's why the user should also have the collection of Friends, where current instance plays a `child` role

```
HasManyToMany(x => x.FriendList2)
    .Table("FriendConnection")
    .ParentKeyColumn("Friend2ID")
    .ChildKeyColumn("Friend1ID");  // reversed mapping
```

the User should be extended like this:

```
public virtual IList<User> FriendList { get; set; }
public virtual IList<User> FriendList2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Should HasManyToMany(x => x.Friends2) be HasManyToMany(x => x.FriendList2) so it is a reference to public virtual IList<User> FriendList2 { get; set; } ?

Comment: I renamed `Friends` to a `FriendList` as you've correcly noted! ;)

Comment: Cool now it made the table! But I am in doubt how am I supposed to add friend relations now? Atm I have http://pastebin.com/BMMsHNvr but as each User now has 2 lists, how do I add friends now?

Comment: Well, good question ;) Hard answer. In *standard* relations many-to-many it is easy, because parent plays just parent role and child is a child. But in here, you should introduce more logic. If a user is adding new friend... it should act as a parent and extend `FriendList`. When user is referenced by someone else, he should act as a child (and will automatically appear in `FriendList2`). Some more business logic, to avoid duplicates and to render relations from both collections ... these will be next steps

Comment: Just in doubt, if user id 1 adds user id 2 as a friend, what data would be in the different lists? And when I look in my list to see who is friends with a certain user, in which list would I look?

Comment: The answer must be in your business logic, hidden from UI layer. There is no easy answer for this model. But you have working NHibernate mapping and it is good starting point, Good luck ;)

Comment: Yes I have hibernate working (Until I switch to mapping by code instead of fluent) and this is my business logic for the previous code http://pastebin.com/BMMsHNvr but my issue is understanding how I should use this new code

Answer (score 1):

Your parameterless constructor does not instantiate your friendslist

```
public User()
{
    Games = new List<Game>();
    Stats = new UserStats { Rating = 1500 };
    FriendList = new List<User>(); // <<<--- missing
 }
```